# Changing time intervals in x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the same data set used for my other questions in this forum.

```
    TimeStamp               data_1     data_2      data_3       
   12/09/2016  15:11:37.474    99.791028   0.312498    99.47853    
   12/09/2016  16:16:22.373    99.791028   0.729162    99.061866   
   12/09/2016  16:21:37.424    99.791028   0.104166    99.686862   
   12/09/2016  17:31:52.475    88.02027                90.520254   
   12/09/2016  17:42:07.157    99.99936    0.208332    99.791028   
   12/09/2016  18:43:22.279    99.99936    0.52083     99.47853    
   12/09/2016  19:45:37.673    99.686862   0           99.686862   
   12/09/2016  20:52:52.872    99.686862   0.729162    98.9577 
   13/09/2016  01:42:07.157    99.99936    0.208332    99.791028   
   13/09/2016  02:43:22.279    99.99936    0.52083     99.47853
```

Question s regarding timestamp column.

currently, I am generating the required graph using below code.

```
ggplot(df, aes(TimeStamp, data_1,group=1)) +geom_point()
```

At present, what will happen is when I used data set with more than 100 timestamps, X-axis will not show anything.

I just need to know

- how to plot timestamps on hourly basis starting from 15th Hour of
  12/09 to 3rd of next day (13/09)
- how to plot data plots on 24 hour basis for both days.

Comment: Format `DateTime` as an actual datetime object (e.g. with `as.POSIXct` or `lubridate::dmy_hms`) so ggplot knows how to parse it. `scale_x_date` will be useful for fine-tuning.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.Would u have code sinppet for this?

Comment: `df$TimeStamp <- lubridate::dmy_hms(df$TimeStamp)` and then plot.